# Android managing bundles passing for large application

Tags: android, bundle

I'm looking for some suggestions to handle bundles for a big application.

In my case, I have tablet application with many screen [40+]. Typically in Android while navigating from one screen to another we pass the bundles that the target screen can use. As there can be many screen navigation paths, it gets cumbersome to manage passing bundles and also some time not efficient to carry data in a screen that is needed only to ensure some other screen gets launched properly.

Is there any generic pattern that gets followed in Android application to handle such cases?

thanks
pradeep

Answer (score 0):

You have to use bundles only to pass the data from one activity to another, in some cases we can use static variables and access the data

Comment: I understand this aspect, but things does not look nice as application gets bigger and bigger. I guess while we still assume small application for mobile handsets, the application for tablet are likely to get as complex as they were for desktop/laptop some year back.  And so I thought probably there may be some generic approach to handle such complicated screen navigations.